# Increase data attribute on click

Tags: jquery, attributes, click, counter

A pretty annoying one, I have got the hard part working, but I am trying to increase the "data-id" on my "content" element when the "next" element is clicked.

So basically when the "data-question" matches the "data-id" it will show.

Not sure why my counter + 1 isn't working, your help will be appreciated.

Thanks

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

$.ajax({
  url: root,
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $('.content').append("<div class='box' data-question='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].title);
  });
  var counter = $('.content').data('id');
  $('.box').hide();
  $('[data-question=' + counter + ']').show();
  
  $('.next').on('click', function() {
     counter + 1
     console.log(counter);
  });

  $('.previous').on('click', function() {
     counter - 1;
     console.log(counter);
  });
});
```

```css
.next {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.previous {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" data-id="1"></div>
<a class="previous" href="#">Previous</a>
<a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code

```
counter + 1;
```

adds 1 to counter, but does nothing with the result.

You need to update the counter variable:

```
counter = counter + 1;
```

or

```
counter += 1;
```

Once you've done that, you can `.hide()` the old value and `.show()` the new one based on the updated counter.  Updated snippet:

```js
var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

$.ajax({
  url: root,
  method: 'GET'
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  $.each(data, function(i, item) {
    $('.content').append("<div class='box' data-question='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].title);
  });
  var counter = $('.content').data('id');
  $('.box').hide();
  $('[data-question=' + counter + ']').show();
  
  $('.next').on('click', function() {
     counter += 1
     console.log(counter);
     $('[data-question]').hide()
     $('[data-question=' + counter + ']').show();

  });

  $('.previous').on('click', function() {
     counter -= 1;
     console.log(counter);
     $('[data-question]').hide()
     $('[data-question=' + counter + ']').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.next {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.previous {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  right: 100px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content" data-id="1"></div>
<a class="previous" href="#">Previous</a>
<a class="next" href="#">Next</a>
```

then you just need to add range checks on the next/prev

---

> I am trying to increase the "data-id"

You don't need to change `data-id` as you're using a local variable (counter).

If you did want to update the data-id, you would use:

```
$('.content').data('id', counter);
```